# Unable to fix Argument Controller is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi This is my first angularjs app and i am facing problem in injecting controller. I have one page called `index.html` and described as below.

```
<body ng-app="RoslpApp">
    <div ng-controller="RoslpAppController">
        <div class="popup">
            <label>Language</label>
            <select ng-model="selectedItem">
                <option>العربية</option>
                <option>English</option>
            </select>
            <button ng-click="clickHandler(selectedItem)">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my js file.

```
var app = angular.module('RoslpApp', ['pascalprecht.translate', 'ui.router']);
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {

    $stateProvider
           // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
           .state('Registration', {
               url: '/Registration',
               templateUrl: 'Registration/Registration.html'
           });
    $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('Main');
    $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
        urlTemplate: "Scripts/Locales/{part}/{lang}.json"
    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_US');
    app.run(function ($rootScope, $translate) {
        $rootScope.$on('$translatePartialLoaderStructureChanged', function () {
            $translate.refresh();
        });
    });
    app.controller('RoslpAppController', ['$scope', '$translate', function ($scope, $translate) {
        $scope.clickHandler = function (key) {
            $translate.use(key);
        };
    }]);
});
```

Whenever i select langualge from the dropdown and click on submit i get Argument `RoslpAppController` is not a function, got undefined error. May i get some help to fix this error?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the controller outside the app.config.

```
app.controller('RoslpAppController', ['$scope', '$translate', function ($scope, $translate) {
    $scope.clickHandler = function (key) {
        $translate.use(key);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Small doubt also i should move out  app.run also right?